# robospice parse nested object response

Tags: android, json, robospice

I have a JSON object returned by the server like:

```
{
 "success":true,
 "value1":1,
 "otherValues":{
     "var1":1,
     "var2":"asd",
     "var3":2
 }
```

}

How should I model the response class to accept all the values? For example

```
package com.phoneme.API.popIndex;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GetResponse {
    private String success
    private String value1;
    private ??? otherValues;

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS of each
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you are trying to decode is not valid JSON. The field names need to be quoted. For example:-

```
{
     "success":true,
     "value1":1,
     "otherValues":{
         "var1":1,
         "var2":"asd",
         "var3":2
     }
 }
```

Using this corrected version of the message, you can generate your POJO here:- http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Good luck!

Comment: I have just written it, it was meant to be valid. I correct it immediatly

Comment: Did you try the generator? That should address your initial question.

Comment: Thanks! it's working. There is only a little problem when I use properties starting with underscore like "_id", telling me that it is unrecognized:
"Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "_id" "

Comment: You can use a PropertyNamingStrategy to solve that. See if http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.html meets your needs. If not it's a simple matter to write your own. Just extend PropertyNamingStrategy.PropertyNamingStrategyBase.